# Is it possible to convert Polygon to centerline linestring?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I have a Polygon which I want to convert to centerline linestring.

[image: Polygon]
**IMAGE 1**

I used the Vector to convert to Polyline but they are not center line as under:

**VECTOR TOOL**

[image]

**IMAGE 2**

Polyline created by the above tool is not **centerline polyline.**

[image]
**IMAGE 3**

**What I am expecting to get is as under (centerline per road, instead of the lines on the side of the road[Image 3]):**

[image]

**IMAGE 4**

Comment: See this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33887/finding-centrelines-from-polygons-in-qgis/33891#33891

Comment: I tried those options but it didnt work. The model implemented by underdark. Also didnt work, it returned empty shape file.

Comment: OpenJUMP has a skeletonizer plugin.

Comment: The  skeletonizer plugin in OpenJUMP needs me to add an input PointSHape Filealong with the Polygon. Hence I cant use it. I need something similar to https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/topographic-production/polygon-to-centerline.htm

Comment: Try to use the capabilities of Whitebox GAT

Comment: If you want to stay in QGIS environment, try [HCMGIS](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HCMGIS/) plugin. (`Geometry processing | Skeleton / Medial Axis`).. it requires QGIS3.0+ though.

Comment: @Kazuhito, i tried but it says.. "Please select 1...100 features to create Skeleton / Media Axis!" I had already select 10.

Comment: @Cyril is it in QGIS ?

Comment: No, this is an open source GIS development and spatial analysis tool with Whitebox GAT

Comment: @Cyril, I went through WhiteBox GAT, unfortunately was not able to find any tool. Did you had anything specific in your mind ?

Comment: I have long solved this problem with the tool "polygons Voronoi" and he met my requirements, for this you need to convert polygons into points and build them "Polygons Voronoi", then convert the result into lines and leave only the axial ones, but As I understand you need the centerlines of the roads, in Whitebox GAT I used the tool EliminateCoincidentPoints, perhaps another...I need to remember...

Comment: @Cyril, I will give it a try as per your suggestions. Yes I want to get the center-line of  Roads. Thanks

Comment: @Cyril it didnt work (not even close to 10%)

Comment: Do you have roads of the same or different widths?

Comment: How many meters wide are the roads?

Comment: Or throw me a snippet of Your data in the format *.shp to: geomaptechnology@gmail.com I'll figure something out...

Comment: The problem is that Your data consists of different shapes: rectangles, circles, trapezoids, etc.and it is difficult to apply a single processing tool to all shapes...

Comment: Second, your data has different directions..

Comment: Have you tried this approach? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269238/create-a-center-line-between-2-polyline-qgis/269259#269259

Comment: @Cyril I had not tried the approach you suggested the last, I will try that. Also I will send you a snippet of the shape file. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Although, I do not understand the last point. Could you be more precise about "running the script in PGAdmin"? Best regards, Xavier

Answer (score 9):

Answer: You can.

I found time for you and hurry to help you.
My answer is now practical.

The original data and table names are fictitious, do not forget to rename them with reference to your example.

Sit in my car and go together to the stop - the "center line of the road."

The initial geodata are polygons of a road network with a width of about 11 m in the EPSG: 4326 coordinate system, broken into segments, see Fig. 1.

[image]

1. In a convenient way for you, create a negative buffer, for example in pgAdmin:

`create table buf_negative as SELECT ST_Buffer (geom, -0.000045) as geom FROM buf_dump;` 
or in QGIS tools: "Vector-Geoprocessing-Buffer Zones".
Thus, we reduced the width of the roads from 11 m to 1 m, see Fig.2

[image]

2. Convert the negative buffer (1 m) into lines, for example with QGIS tools:
   "Vector-Processing geometry-polygons in a line" result see Fig. 3

[image]

3. Extract from the lines of the point, for example with the QGIS tools: "Vector-Processing geometry-Extract nodes", the result see Fig. 4

[image]

4. Create point buffers from them, so that they intersect each other,
   Further combine them with each other using the tool "Vector>Geoprocessing>Merge" and extract centroids from adjacent buffers, the result is shown in Fig. 5
   (centroids are red dots)

[image]

5. From the centroid points, create the Delaunay Triangulation, for example with the QGIS tools: "Vector-Processing geometry-Delaunay triangulation", and trim the result with your 1 m negative buffer polygons, see the result of Fig. 6

[image]

6. Blast the lines into segments, for example, using QGIS Desktop with GRASS tools: "Data Analysis - Lines-Explode Lines", see Fig. 7

[image]

7. Run the following script in PGAdmin:

`create table buf_centre_ln as SELECT ST_Intersection (a.geom, b.geom) AS geom FROM explode_ln as a JOIN buf_negative as b ON ST_Within (a.geom, b.geom);`

see the result in Fig. 8

[image]

9. Remove duplicating lines and do with the center lines, whatever,

Answer (score 2):

The library [pygeoops](https://pygeoops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) also has an implementation to calculate a centerline of a polygon: [pygeoops.centerline](https://pygeoops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pygeoops.centerline.html#pygeoops.centerline). It also removes short branches, simplifies the result,... to get a "clean" result.

Sample script:

```
import pygeoops
import shapely

polygon = shapely.from_wkt("POLYGON ((0 0, 0 8, -2 10, 4 10, 2 8, 2 2, 10 2, 10 0, 0 0))")
centerline = pygeoops.centerline(polygon)
```

Result:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of pygeoops

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve it, on PostgresGis, with one of the options of the free tool "geom8tricks" With the "PolygonsToLines" option, once you select the origin polygons and the destination Database connection has been correctly configured, you get the line objects, centered on the polygons . The program does it in two stages, in a first one it obtains the decomposition of the polygon in lines, by means of st_skeleton function

In a second stage, the longest line of all those that make up the object is selected 
[image: Select the longest line]

The problem of intersections is solved whenever there is a primary key column in the origin polygons, which allows to distinguish between the objects that intersect
[image: Line Intersection]

Comment: What ist PostgreGis???

Comment: PostGIS, See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/473070/88814

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the Geom8tricks suggestion above and found this link which seems to also include the PolygonToLines feature. I haven't used it myself.

For anyone still looking for this I think he's referring to http://geom8tricks.com/index_ml.html?lang=en

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/246174)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library centerline 1.0.1.

https://centerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/issues

On github for the lib centerline  (issues) user [Turtle6665](https://github.com/Turtle6665) proposed an alternative solution for shapely 2.0 and geopandas.

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

def construct_centerline(input_geometry, interpolation_distance=0.5):
   #find the voronoi verticies (equivalent to Centerline._get_voronoi_vertices_and_ridges())
   borders = input_geometry.segmentize(interpolation_distance) #To have smaler verticies (equivalent to Centerline._get_densified_borders())
   voronoied = shapely.voronoi_polygons(borders,only_edges=True) #equivalent to the scipy.spatial.Voronoi
   
   #to select only the linestring within the input geometry (equivalent to Centerline._linestring_is_within_input_geometry)
   centerlines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(voronoied.geoms)).sjoin(gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries(input_geometry)),predicate="within")
   return centerlines.unary_union

centerlines = construct_centerline(open_area_Road[0],interpolation_distance=0.5)
```