# how to get a low level road network from openstreetmap data?

Tags: openstreetmap, road, generalization, skeleton

I've extracted the road network of a city from openstreetmaps (filetype: osm). One part of the road networks look like this:
[image]

However, there are too many details in this data.
I'd like to represent each road with just one linestring, just like this:
[image]

Is there any convenient (or maybe a tricky) way to reach that?
I've searched around our site, I found some map skeletonization/genratzation may help, but I'm not quite sure about that. I've also tried the "network toplogy cleaning" function in OpenJUMP, but it didn't work.
I would very happy to see a software/library can help me on this.

Or, is there any alternative way to extract rough(low level) road network of a city from other map source?

Comment: Looks like this is a very similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/how-can-i-merge-collapse-nearby-and-parallel-road-lines-eg-a-dual-carriageway

Answer (score 1):

A russian mapper has made [a tool](https://github.com/OverQuantum/mp_extsimp) for road network generalization, but it has three drawbacks:

1. It's in Visual Basic.
2. It reads and produces `.mp` files made with [osm2mp](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2mp).
3. [Documentation](https://github.com/OverQuantum/mp_extsimp/wiki) is in Russian.

Sadly, @Mapper is right: there is no such general-purpose solution not only for OpenStreetMap data, but in general, for any open geodata format.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is currently no ready to use solution to generalize a (per lane) roadnetwork and reduce the complexity.